# Sum of squares of consecutive integers equals to a square

Tags: quadratics, square-numbers

I am not at all mathematics guy, just had a question. How can I find possible pairs of consecutive integers whose sum of squares equals to a square?

I understand equation will be something like:

x² + (x + 1)² = y²

x² + x² + 2x + 1 = y2

2x² + 2x + 1 = y²

where x, x+1 consecutive integers.

But, how can I mathematically find (x, x+1) pairs, example:

3² + 4² = 5²

20² + 21² = 29²

119² + 120² = 169²

from the equation? I am actually trying to write a program which will find these pairs without brute force. Please help me with the logic (maths).

Is there a possible way to find these pairs without "substituting x by every number from 1 to n and checking if y² is a perfect square"? I mean to avoid brute force or decrease brute force complexity, maybe like simplifying the equation 2x² + 2x + 1 = y² even more.

Comment: Please search if your question exists on [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) before asking here. These numbers are called Pythagorean triples, named after Pythagoras' theorem ($a^2+b^2=c^2$).

Comment: @TobyMak  Well...is it obvious how to pass from the general form of a Pythagorean triple to one of the type the OP desires?  That is $a^2+(a+1)^2=c^2$?  I wouldn't think that was trivial...you still need to solve a Pell type equation.  See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TwinPythagoreanTriple.html) for instance.  Note that the discussion on that link also considers the triples in which the hypotenuse is $1$ greater than one leg.

Comment: @lulu  Below I have provided $3$ methods of generating $B-A=\pm1$ but you mentioned a hypotenuse-leg difference of $1$. Here is a bit of non-trivia you might find fascinating.

One easy way to generate triples where
$C-B=1$ or $C-A=2$ is to begin with a variation of Euclid's formula:

$$ A=(2n-1+k)^2-k^2\quad B=2(2n-1+k)k \quad C=(2n-1+k)^2+k^2$$
Using this formula;

$$n=1\implies C-B=1\qquad k=1\implies C-A=2$$

Comment: @poetasis  Oh, that's very nice, thanks!  Your posted solution is quite thorough as well (+1).

Comment: @lulu Nice, but this has been asked many times here.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least $3$ ways of generating these. Note that these are so rare that the $20^{th}$ triple exceeds $15$ digits.

We begin with Euclid's formula shown here as:
$$ A=m^2-k^2\qquad B=2mk \qquad C=m^2+k^2$$

The $m,k$ values for
$\space A^2+(A\pm1)^2=C^2\space$ are
[pell numbers](https://oeis.org/A000129)

$$p\in\big\{0,1,2,5,12,29,70,169,\cdots\big\} \space e.g.$$

$$
F(1,0)=(1,0,1)\\
F(2,1)=(3,4,5)\\
F(5,2)=(21,20,29)\\
F(12,5)=(119,120,169)\\
F(29,12)=(697,696,985)\\
F(70,29)=(4059,4060,5741)\\
F(169,70)=(23661,23660,33461)\\
\vdots$$

1. The $n^{th}\space$ $(m,k)\space$ pair may be generated directly by the following formula.

\begin{equation}
 m_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^{n+1} - (1 - \sqrt{2})^{n+1}}{2\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 k_n= \frac{(1 + \sqrt{2})^n - (1 - \sqrt{2})^n}{2\sqrt{2}}
 \end{equation}

2. These pairs may also be generated sequentially by
   \begin{equation}
   \quad m=k+\sqrt{2k^2+(-1)^k}
   \end{equation}
3. The $A,B,C$ values may be generated without Euclid's formula by using the following formula with a seed [invalid] triple  $T_0=(0,0,1)$.
   \begin{equation}
   A_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+1\\  
   B_{n+1}=3A_n+2C_n+2 \\ 
   C_{n+1}=4A_n+3C_n+2
   \end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

According to Euclid's formula, we have $$ a=m^2-n^2, b=2mn, c=m^2+n^2$$
You are asking for $$m^2-n^2=2mn\pm 1 $$ Upon adding $2n^2$ to both sides we get
$$(m-n)^2=2n^2\pm 1$$
Thus we choose positive integers $n$ such that one of $2n^2\pm 1 $ is a perfect square and solve $$ (m-n)^2=2n^2\pm 1$$ for $m$
For example:

$$n=1, 2n^2-1=1, (m-1)^2=1, m=2$$ which gives us $$(a,b,c)=(3,4,5)$$
$$ n=2, 2n^2+1=9, (m-2)^2=9, m=5$$ which gives us $$ (a,b,c)=(21,20,29)$$
With $n=5$ we get $$(a,b,c)= (119,120,169)$$
With $n=12$ we get $$(a,b,c)= (697,696,985)$$
And with $n=985$ we get $$(a,b,c)= (4684659,4684660,6625109)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=2x+1$ and let $Y=y$, then we get $$X^2-2Y^2=-1\tag{1}$$

The equation $X^2-2Y^2=-1$ is called as Pell's equation.

For details, see [Pell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

All solutions are given as follows.
Let  $(X_{0},Y_{0})$ is a fundamental solution of $X^{2}-2Y^{2}=-1.$

Thus, all of the solutions are derived from $(X_{0}+Y_{0}\sqrt{2})^n$ where $n$ is an odd integer.

Clearly, we know  $(X_{0},Y_{0})=(1,1)$.

We take the integer part as $X$ and the coefficient of $\sqrt{2}$ as $Y$ as follows.

$(1+1\sqrt{2})^{3} = 7+5\sqrt{2} \implies (X,Y)=(7,5) \implies (x,y)=(3,5).$
$(1+1\sqrt{2})^{5} = 41+29\sqrt{2} \implies (X,Y)=(41,29) \implies (x,y)=(20,29).$
$(1+1\sqrt{2})^{7} = 239+169\sqrt{2} \implies (X,Y)=(239,169) \implies (x,y)=(119, 169).$

Thus, we can get the infinitely many integer solutions of equation $(1).$

```
                          [x,y]
                          [3, 5], 
                          [20, 29], 
                          [119, 169], 
                          [696, 985], 
                          [4059, 5741], 
                          [23660, 33461], 
                          [137903, 195025], 
                          [803760, 1136689], 
                          [4684659, 6625109], 
                          [27304196, 38613965],
```